# Difference between &param and :&param in ruby methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have functions with the definition `def test(&param)` and `def test(:&param)`. What is the difference between both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def test(&block) ...
```

means that our method accepts a block:

```
def test(number, &block)
  yield number
  # same as
  # block.call number
end
test(10) {|a| a+a}
#=> 20
# or
block = proc{|a| a*a}
test 10, &block
#=> 100
```

While `def test(:&param)` will throw an error.

Also you can call something like `method(&:operator)`:

```
[1,2,3].inject(&:+)
#=> 6
```

That is the same as

```
[1,2,3].inject{|sum, i| sum+i }
```

Comment: It doesn't mean your method accepts a block, it means you want to store it in a Proc object if it is passed — which you don't want, unless you are going to pass the block to another method or to store it for later use.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that `def test(:&param)` causes a syntax error and `def test(&param)` does not.